# Editing (correctly) a .txt list in Python

Tags: python, text, edit

Having a list in a .txt file that reads:

```
Start
Edit
Edit
Edit
ERROR
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
Edit
Edit
Edit
```

How to edit just the "Edit" words between "Start" and "ERROR" but NOT the "Edit" words between "ERROR" and "Start", to end with a list that reads:

```
Start
Edited
Edited
Edited
ERROR
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
Edited
Edited
Edited
```

My code until the moment:

```
import os
import os.path
import re

source = 'C:\\records'
lines = []
linenr = []
linenum = 0
pattern = re.compile("Start")
pattern1 = re.compile("Edit")
pattern2 = re.compile("ERROR")

replacements = {'Edit':'Edited'}



for fname in os.listdir(source):
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    if ext.lower().endswith(('.txt', '.TXT')):
        f = open(os.path.join(source, fname))
        for line in f:
            linenum += 1
            if pattern.search(line):
                editor = "OK"
            elif pattern2.search(line):
                editor = "NOK"
            if editor == "OK":
                if pattern1.search(line):
                    linenr.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
                    for src, target in replacements.items():
                        lines.append(line)
                
        continue
    
for i in linenr:
    print("At line " + str(i[0]) + " Found an editable line")

with open(source + "\\" + fname, 'r+') as outfile:
    for line in lines:
        outfile.write(line.replace(src, target))

f.close()
```

I can get the correct list of records that are editable with `print("At line " + str(i[0]) + " Found an editable line")`
But my file turns out like:

```
Edited
Edited
Edited
Edited
Edited
Editedit
Start
Edit
Edit
Edit
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path = "test.txt"
savepath = "output.txt"

# Read lines from file to list and strip them
# to get read from special characters
with open(path) as file:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in file.readlines()]
    
# Flag shows can we change Edit to Edited or not
flag = True

# Loop through all values and change needed
for i, l in enumerate(lines):
    if l == 'Start':
        flag = True
    elif l == 'Edit' and flag:
        lines[i] = 'Edited'
    elif l == 'ERROR':
        flag = False

# Save result        
with open(savepath, "w+") as file:
    file.writelines('\n'.join(lines))
```

P.S. In Python 3.10+ instead of if/elif you can use match/case

Answer (score 0):

Say your starting list is:

```
Start
Edit
Edit
Edit
ERROR
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
Edit
Edit
Edit
ERROR
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
```

This code will change the "Edit" values only if they come between a "Start" and "ERROR" value:

```py
path = "Text.txt"
save = "Save.txt"

textList = [f for f in open(path)]
start = [i for i, s in enumerate(textList) if "Start" in s] # Find all indexes for "Start"
error = [i for i, s in enumerate(textList) if "ERROR" in s] # Find all indexes for "ERROR"

# Grab all the indexes where Start is proceeded by an ERROR
List = []
for x in range(len(start)-1):
    for y in range(len(error)):
        if error[y] > start[x] and error[y] < start[x+1]: # Only grabs the index if there is an ERROR after this Start index
            List.append([start[x]+1,error[y]]) #"start[x] + 1" to get the index of the "Edit" string that came after the "Start" string
            break
errorDF = pd.DataFrame(List, columns=["Start", "Error"]) # Hold these values in a dataframe for easy access

# Loop through these indexes to ensure you are only changing the Edits that are sandwiched between a Start and an ERROR
for begin,end in zip(errorDF.Start, errorDF.Error):
    for x in list(range(begin, end)):
        textList[x] = textList[x].replace('Edit', 'Edited')       

# Save to a new text file
with open(save, "w+") as file:
    file.writelines(textList)
```

Output:

```
Start
Edited
Edited
Edited
ERROR
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
Edited
Edited
Edited
ERROR
Edit
Edit
Edit
Start
```